# Como definir varios roles a un mismo controlador usando use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;?

Tags: php, symfony2

```
use AppBundle\Tests\Controller\HojaRutaControllerTest;

//use Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Chofer;
//use Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Omnibus;
//use Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Ruta;
//use Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\HojaRuta;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use AppBundle\Entity\Recaudacion;
use AppBundle\Form\RecaudacionType;

/**
 *
 * Función para llamar a la plantilla de administración
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 *
 *
 */
class RecaudacionController extends Controller
{
```

Comment: Agrega la etiqueta del framework que usas

Comment: use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

Comment: cuando utilizo un solo rol me funciona pero quiero usar varios roles en um mismo controlador

Comment: O sea con este metodo en el controlador me funciona:

Comment: * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")

Comment: pero solo me le da perminso a los usuarios con el rol admin quiero que otros loles tambien tengas acceso

Comment: Mira te sugiero que todas esas aclaraciones que das en los comentarios los pongas como parte de la pregunta, para añadir más claridad a la pregunta, ya que no explicas nada en ella... y que podamos entenderte mejor que es lo que quieres hacer... que me parece que no está muy clara tu idea... saludos

Answer (score 0):

@Security admite expresiones, por lo que puedes expresarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
use AppBundle\Tests\Controller\HojaRutaControllerTest;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use AppBundle\Entity\Recaudacion;
use AppBundle\Form\RecaudacionType;

/**
 *
 * Función para llamar a la plantilla de administración
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN') or has_role('OTRO_ROL')")
 *
 *
 */
class RecaudacionController extends Controller
{
```

Otra forma de hacerlo es que generes un ROL específico para esta acción, por ejemplo ROLE_RECAUDACION, y que todos los roles que necesites que tengan acceso a esta función hereden de él. Luego solo tienes que comprobar ese rol específico en lugar de comprobar uno o varios roles. Esta opción es muy práctica de cara a que en un futuro lo requerimientos cambien y otros roles necesiten acceder a esta (o cualquier otra) funcionalidad. Solo tiene que añadir el rol específico a los otros roles que te interesen.